# Backbone.js cannot merge attributes when using template?

Tags: backbone.js, underscore.js

I've just started learning backbone.js and ran into my first problem. I'd like to inject attributes in `User` view using `attributes` property instead of writing them in my template itself:

```
<div id="lista"></div>

<script type="text/template" id="user-template">
    <a class="btn" href="#"><i class="icon-user"></i>
    <%= first %> <%= last %></a>
</script>
```

```js
window.UserView = Backbone.View.extend({
    attributes : { "data-route" : '/users/' + this.name },
    template: _.template($('#user-template').html()),
    initialize : function() {
        _.bindAll(this, "render");
    },
    render : function() {
        $(this.el).html(this.template(this.model.toJSON()));
        return this;
    }
});

var u = new User({ first : 'First', last : 'Last' });
var v = new UserView({ model : u, el : '#lista' });

v.render();
```

Output is missing `data-route` attribute:

```
<div id="lista">
    <a href="#" class="btn"><i class="icon-user"></i> First Last</a>
</div>
```

Can you confirm that `attributes` doesn't work with `template`?

Answer (score 4):

`template` uses the hash passed as argument, in your case you can merge `this.model.toJSON()` and `this.attributes`

Try

```
render: function() {
    var data = _.extend(this.model.toJSON(), this.attributes);
    this.$el.html(this.template(data));
    return this;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Specifically from the docs:

> `attributes` `model.attributes`
>
> The attributes property is the internal hash containing the model's state. Please use set to update the attributes instead of modifying them directly. If you'd like to retrieve and munge a copy of the model's attributes, use `toJSON` instead